# Create new tmux session from inside a tmux session

Tags: tmux

I'm writing a shell script that creates / attaches or switches to a given session, depending on whether one is inside tmux and the session exists.

I've got everything working great except for the case requiring the creation of a new tmux session from within a tmux session.

When my script executes `tmux new-session -s name`, I get the following output:

> sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force

I don't actually want to nest sessions, my goal is to **create another separate session and switch to it from within a tmux session**.

Is this possible?

Comment: A GREAT resource for users finding this question: https://leanpub.com/the-tao-of-tmux/read

Answer (score 222, accepted):

The quickest way (assuming you use `ctrl-b` as your command prefix) is:

```
ctrl-b :new
```

To create a new session, then

```
ctrl-b s
```

to interactively select and attach to the session.

Comment: +1 for solution that doesn't care about "sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force"

Comment: and then you could rename your session : `ctrl-b $`

Comment: And `Ctrl-b :new -s <name>` to give a name to the new session.

Comment: @AinTohvri If your comment was an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: If you want to attach (if the session exists) or create with the same command, you can use `Ctrl-b :new -As <name>`

Answer (score 50):

## How to create the script

This script will check if a session exists.  If session does not exist create new session and attach to it.  If session does exist nothing happens and we attach to that session.  Feel free to replace `~/development' with project name.

`$ touch ~/development && chmod +x ~/development`

```
# ~/development

tmux has-session -t development
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
  tmux new-session -s development
fi
tmux attach -t development
```

## New session from terminal

Let's create two detached sessions, list them, attach to one and then from within tmux cycle through sessions.

`tmux new -s name -d` works from inside tmux because we're creating a new detached session.  Otherwise you'll get a nesting error.

```
$ tmux new -s development -d
$ tmux new -s foo -d
$ tmux ls
> development: 1 windows (created Wed Jan 13 11:31:38 2016) [204x54]
> foo: 1 windows (created Wed Jan 13 11:31:38 2016) [204x54]
$ tmux attach -t
$ tmux ls
> development: 1 windows (created Wed Jan 13 11:31:38 2016) [204x54] (attached)
> foo: 1 windows (created Wed Jan 13 11:31:38 2016) [204x54]
```

## New session from within tmux

We are now inside or better known as **attached** to our target session.  If we try to create a new session while attached it will result in a nesting error.

```
$ tmux new -s bar
> sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

To solve this we create a new detached session. e.g.,

```
$ tmux new -s bar -d
$ tmux ls
> development: 1 windows (created Wed Jan 13 11:31:38 2016) [204x54] (attached)
> foo: 1 windows (created Wed Jan 13 11:31:38 2016) [204x54]
> bar: 1 windows (created Wed Jan 13 17:19:35 2016) [204x54]
```

Cycle (switch) Sessions

- `Prefix` `(` **previous session**
- `Prefix` `)` **next session**

**note:** `Prefix` is `Ctrl-b`by default. You can bind `Prefix` to `Ctrl-a` and in Mac OSX you can change Caps Lock to ctrl `system preferences > keyboard > modifier keys`

## Attach to a session using command mode while inside tmux

Trying to attach to a session without detaching will result in an error.

```
$ tmux attach -t development
> sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

Instead use command mode `Prefix` `:` then type `attach -t session_name` and hit enter.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer, this answered a few of my questions all at once!

Comment: What might output `no current client` with such a setup on the default config on the very first attach to a new main Tmux session? For example, `TMUX='' tmux new-session -ds 'main'; exec tmux attach -t 'main';` outside of Tmux and without `main` prior set.

Answer (score 29):

Using this works for me:

```
TMUX= tmux new-session -d -s name
tmux switch-client -t name
```

The `TMUX=` on the first line is required so tmux doesn't throw a `sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force` message.

Comment: Works great in my script after changing first line to: `TMUX=\`tmux new-session -d -s name\``

Comment: @MichaelRobinson, that just coincidentally working for you. Backticks are used to capture output from a command, but `tmux new-session -d -s name` does not generate any output to capture. Rather it's the fact than `name` is shared between the two commands.

Comment: shorthand: `tmux switchc -t "$(tmux new -dP)"`

Answer (score 20):

All the commands you can launch within your terminal, like `tmux new -s sessionName` can be launched from within `tmux` by pressing the trigger key (eg: `ctrl-b`) then `:` then the command without the starting `tmux` part.

As a result, `ctrl-b :` followed by `new -s sessionName` will do exactly what you want and give a name to your session. It also switches automatically to the new session.

Answer (score 13):

You can try `unset TMUX` first, this works for me.

Comment: this will nest tmux and isn't recommended

Answer (score 8):

at user2354696's advice I use following key bindings to create a new session or "clone" an existing session

```
bind-key N run-shell 'TMUX= tmux new-session -d \; switch-client -n'
bind-key C run-shell 'TMUX= tmux new-session -t $(tmux display-message -p #S) -s $(tmux display-message -p #S-clone) -d \; switch-client -n \; display-message "session #S cloned"'
```

Answer (score 7):

### TL;DR

```
tmux switchc -t `tmux new -dP`
```

### How it works

To create a new session and switch to it, from insde a tmux session and without using tmux commands, you need to do it in two steps.

1. Create the session with `new-session` in a detatched way with `-d`, print out the name with `-P`. Capture this output.

```
NEW_SESSION=`tmux new-session -dP`
```

2. Use the output to switch the client (your terminal window) to different session with `switch-client`. Pass your new session as the target with `-t`.

```
tmux switch-client -t $NEW_SESSION
```

#### One-liner

You can create a one-liner that does this:

```
tmux switch-client -t `tmux new-session -dP`
```

or in shorthand:

```
tmux switchc -t `tmux new -dP`
```

Comment: This a good variation to the accepted answer

Comment: Awesome answer and mostly what I was looking for.
I found that if binding to a key the `tmux` is not needed and just `new-session` will also bring you to the newly created session.  In other words  `bind-key -N "New Client Session" C-a new-session` will create the new session and then switch to that as well (as far as I see I don't have any other settings to automagically switch to the new session when created)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398850/create-new-tmux-session-from-inside-a-tmux-session/76371972#comment47958386_21272658), use

```
Ctrl-b :new -s <name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [`zsh/zle`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html) function `tmx`:

- When invoked from the command line as just `tmx` or using a bound key (my case below `F4`) it invokes [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to quickly switch to available tmux sessions with auto-completion and session preview on the right.

  (The function was inspired by https://waylonwalker.com/tmux-fzf-session-jump/, see also [Quick jump to tmux session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709860/22339).)
- When invoked as `tmux my-session` it attaches to or creates a new session `my-session`.
- It works both within and outside an existing session. If invoked within a session it switches the client.

```bash
function tmx {
    [ -n "$ZLE_STATE" ] && trap 'zle reset-prompt' EXIT
    local tmux item
    tmux="$(which tmux)" || return $?
    if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
        item="$($tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name}' |\
            fzf --header jump-to-session --preview "$tmux capture-pane -pt {}")" || return 2
    else
        item="$1"
    fi
    (
        # Restore the standard std* file descriptors for tmux.
        # https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512979/22339
        exec </dev/tty; exec <&1;
        if [ -z "$TMUX" ] ; then
            # Running insided tmux.
            $tmux new-session -As "$item"
        else
            # Attempt to create a new session in case there none with that name.
            $tmux new-session -ds "$item" 2>/dev/null || true
            $tmux switch-client -t "$item"
        fi
    )
}
zle -N tmx
bindkey '\eOS' tmx  # Bind the function to F4.
```