# How to create byobu session inside byobu with a bashcommand

Tags: tmux, byobu

So I have a setup with `guake`, `byobu` and `tmux` as backend. I want to have different folders already open in my console for work projects and these projects in individual sessions 
I get the following message when I try to

```
tmux new -s contract-service
```

or

```
byobu -S my-other-session
```

> sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force

of course, because it already has the session open and I am typing it in it. 
So my question is, how do I write a bash script the `byobu` shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+F2` because this is exactly what I want.

This works for me now:

```
xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shift+F2

tmux rename-session $SESSION
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tmux new-session -d -s name`

duplicate of [Create new tmux session from inside a tmux session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398850/create-new-tmux-session-from-inside-a-tmux-session?rq=1)

Finally found it, was looking for this forever.